# Rest bundle class not found

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I use `FOSRest Bundle` with `FOSUser` to create registration form using API.
When I debug the `FOSRestController.php`, I receive this message:

> Fatal error: Class
>   'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller' not found in
>   D:\e-electricity.com\vendor\friendsofsymfony\rest-bundle\FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController.php
>   on line 24

I tried composer update to remove cache but I still receiving the same message.

```
abstract class FOSRestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Creates a view.
     *
     * Convenience method to allow for a fluent interface.
     *
     * @param mixed $data
     * @param int   $statusCode
     * @param array $headers
     *
     * @return View
     */
    protected function view($data = null, $statusCode = null, array $headers = array())
    {
        return View::create($data, $statusCode, $headers);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Redirect view.
     *
     * Convenience method to allow for a fluent interface.
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param int    $statusCode
     * @param array  $headers
     *
     * @return View
     */
    protected function redirectView($url, $statusCode = Codes::HTTP_FOUND, array $headers = array())
    {
        return View::createRedirect($url, $statusCode, $headers);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Route Redirect View.
     *
     * Convenience method to allow for a fluent interface.
     *
     * @param string $route
     * @param mixed  $parameters
     * @param int    $statusCode
     * @param array  $headers
     *
     * @return View
     */
    protected function routeRedirectView($route, array $parameters = array(), $statusCode = Codes::HTTP_CREATED, array $headers = array())
    {
        return View::createRouteRedirect($route, $parameters, $statusCode, $headers);
    }

    /**
     * Converts view into a response object.
     *
     * Not necessary to use, if you are using the "ViewResponseListener", which
     * does this conversion automatically in kernel event "onKernelView".
     *
     * @param View $view
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    protected function handleView(View $view)
    {
        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try deleting the vendor folder and running "composer install" again? Maybe followed by a "php bin/console cache:clear"?

Comment: I tried composer install and compser install --prefer-dist and i clear cach but still the same problem

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using? Can you show your composer.json?

Comment: "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",

Comment: You are using the complete Symfony framework?  You can check under vendor for the framework bundle.  But I suspect you are doing something else completely.

Comment: Yes i use Symfony and i hava an Api Rest , and i find that the problem is from this APi but i don(t understand why

Comment: Is the code you posted your own code?  I assume there is a "use Symfony...Controller" statement at the top?  I suppose you could also check to see if vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php has an entry for FrameworkBundle.  But as long as you used composer to install everything (or maybe the symfony app) then it should be fine.  You could always just make a new project to test.

Comment: i'm working on existing project so it's not my code . Those are all the uses in the file  :

Comment: use ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\Entity\TenderBookmark;
use ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\Entity\TenderCategory;
use ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\Entity\Tender;
use ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\Entity\Category;
use ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\Entity\Buyer;
use ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\Entity\Supplier;

Comment: use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\QueryParam;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Post;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Put;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcherInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\Util\Codes;

Comment: use FOS\RestBundle\View\View AS FOSView;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager;
use Proxies\__CG__\ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\Entity\Bid;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use ContinuousNet\UbidElectricityBundle\EventListener\UserSessionData;

Comment: You may have noticed that comment formatting leaves something to be desired.  Typically you would use the edit button to update your question.  But I see you opened another question up which implies that this one has now been solved.